# SQL Server : get rows with customers that have never purchased online

Tags: sql-server

I have a table `TransactionData` that contains transaction data for customers and another table `Subscribers` that contains customers that are newsletter subscribers.

This is what I need to do: select all subscribers from `TransactionData` table that are also in the `Subscribers` table and that have never purchased products online (`StoreID = 50001`).

The unique key for both tables is the customer email address.

This is the basic table structure.

TransactionData

```
Email               StoreID OrderID
customer1@mail.com  50001   101
customer1@mail.com  50001   102
customer2@mail.com  50001   201
customer2@mail.com  51111   202
customer3@mail.com  50001   301
customer3@mail.com  50001   302
```

Subscribers

```
Email
customer1@mail.com
customer2@mail.com
```

Desired result

```
Email               StoreID
customer1@mail.com  51111
```

This is my query so far:

```
SELECT 
    b.Email, b.BoutiqueId
FROM 
    HasNewsletterPermission2014 AS a
INNER JOIN 
    TransactionData AS b ON a.Email = b.Email
WHERE 
    b.BoutiqueId <> 50001
```

I can't figure out how to exclude customers that have never purchased online.

Can you help me with this?

Comment: according to your requirement, the query should return NO ROWS

Comment: Or just change your INNER join to a LEFT join and add a where predicate "where b.Email IS NULL"

Comment: The example and the description are not equivalent, the difference being your example yields a customer where the transaction was not an online order and the description/request is for customers who have NEVER had an online order.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `IN`:

```
SELECT b.Email, b.BoutiqueId
FROM HasNewsletterPermission2014 AS a
INNER JOIN TransactionData AS b
ON a.Email = b.Email
WHERE b.email not in (select email from TransactionData where BoutiqueId = 50001)
```

This allows you to select all individuals who have not had an online transaction.

Or you can use `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT b.Email, b.BoutiqueId
FROM HasNewsletterPermission2014 AS a
INNER JOIN TransactionData AS b
ON a.Email = b.Email
WHERE not exists (select td.email from TransactionData td where b.email = td.email and td.BoutiqueId = 50001)
```

Both achieve the same outcome.